# I want to energize a solenoid based on a temperature without arduino?

Tags: analog, power-electronics

I want to open a 12V solenoid valve and close another based on a temperature reading I will be getting from the [lm35dz](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm35.pdf) temperature sensor. I should mention, the solenoids are normally closed and they will be activated through relays that are connected to the arduino board.

I think I can do this project with an arduino board, but I was wondering, is it possible to accomplish this same task using electronic components ?

Comment: Are you familiar with comparators and hysteresis? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparator for example http://www.eeweb.com/blog/extreme_circuits/temperature-controlled-switch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could build a comparator circuit around an LM339 (or similar), a voltage reference, and your LM35. However, this is such a common application that there are temperature sensors with built in alert outputs such as the LTC2996 that have it all in one package. http://www.linear.com/product/LTC2996. It's a linear temperature sensor with a built in comparator. You set the thresholds by resistor selection.

Comment: In this case OP would connect a N-Channel Transistor or Mosfet to the OT (Over Temperature) pin, and the solenoid trigger pins accordingly.